# spawnv call with array of array of char (char* argv[])

Tags: c++

id like to spawn a process with unknown number of parameters.
my code so far (using power++):

```
char** psaParameters = new char*[ saParameters.GetCount() ];

            for( int i = 0; i < saParameters.GetCount(); i++ )
            {
                psaParameters[ i ] = new char[ saParameters[ i ].GetLength() ];
                strcpy( psaParameters[ i ], saParameters[ i ].GetText() );
            }

            spawnv( P_WAIT, psaParameters[ 0 ], psaParameters );
```

but it's crashing. why?

thank you!
-dominik

Answer (score 2):

What type `saParameters[i]` is?

Probably you need to change this line to:

```
psaParameters[ i ] = new char[ saParameters[ i ].GetLength() + 1 ];
```

to include the zero-terminator.

Answer (score 0):

What is the type of `saParameters`? My guess, without knowing that is that `GetLength()` returns the number of characters not including a NUL terminator. Since `strcpy` automatically adds this it would result in overflowing each of the buffers inside the `saParameters` array.

Answer (score 0):

You don't allocate enough space for the terminating null character.

```
 psaParameters[ i ] = new char[ saParameters[ i ].GetLength() ];
```

should be

```
 psaParameters[ i ] = new char[ saParameters[ i ].GetLength() + 1 ];
```

Answer (score 0):

ok we found out what the problem was:

1. the GetLength() + 1 was correct - thank you ;)
2. the last array element (pointer) in psaParameters had to be NULL so the spawnv()-method knows when to stop reading arguments from the argument-array.